# Error: Username already exists [403] Meteor

Tags: meteor, meteor-accounts

I have manually created a user on a meteor app with Accounts.createUser and have disabled sign ups so this is the only user. This worked until I restarted the server and started getting this error:

Error: Username already exists. [403]

I have Accounts.createUser under if (Meteor.isServer), I suspect where I created the user may be the issue. Thoughts?

Comment: Is `Accounts.createUser` inside a meteor method or literally just wrapped in `if (Meteor.isServer)`? If the latter, it will try to create the user every time you start the server...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're running `Accounts.createUser` every time you run your app.

Try doing this, which will only create a user if there are none in your collection.

```
if(Meteor.isServer) {
    if(!Meteor.users.findOne()) {

        Accounts.createUser(....)

    }
}
```